# Add text excerpt and pictures to hyperlinks?

Tags: links, excerpt

Is there a way to automatically add text excerpts and perhaps also pictures when one adds a hyperlink into ones post?
A bit like when you e.g. share hyperlinks on LinkedIn?
Thanks for any suggestions
Regards
Peter